# In Windows Azure, is it possible to have a load balanced endpoint that's only accessible by traffic from a connected virtual network?

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-virtual-network

I have a Cloud Service that is connected to a LAN through a virtual network. I have a web role that machines on the LAN will be hitting for tasks like telling the cloud service that data needs to be refreshed. It it possible to have and endpoint that's load-balanced, but that only accepts traffic through the virtual network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... you have a few things to think about.

You could set up your own load balancer in a separate role, which then does the load balancing. You'd probably want two instances to deal with high availability, and if there was any stateful/sticky-session data you'd need to sync it between your two load balancers. OR...

Now: If your code needing load-balancing lived in a Virtual Machine, rather than in a web/worker role, you could take advantage of the brand-new IP-level endpoint ACL feature introduced at TechEd. With this feature, you can have an endpoint that allows/blocks traffic based on source IP address. So you could have a load-balanced endpoint balancing traffic between a few virtual machines, and you could then limit access to, say, your LAN machines, and even add your existing Cloud Service (web/worker) VIP so that your web and worker role instances could access the service, all through the endpoint without going through the VPN. This way, you'd get to take advantage of Azure's built-in load balancer, while at the same time providing secure access for your app's services.

You can see more details of endpoint ACLs [here](http://michaelwasham.com/2013/06/03/windows-azure-powershell-june-2013-update-for-iaas-and-paas/).

Answer (score 0):

No. The load balancer for a cloud service is public only. You can't predict the ip addresses of the individual instances on the virtual network, so you can't even hook them into your own load balancer. Yes, you can do it with VMs (as David recommends) — but then you're doing old-school IIS, not a cloud service. I went through this in November 2012, and was [unable to find a decent solution](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/7708ab26-c2f8-4e3a-ad91-4faa9f9644d9/internal-ip-address-of-role-load-balancer#1f340d34-d4c9-444a-b446-e5fed02a489f).